# Java, quickest way to determine if any values in hashmap match a value?

Tags: java, dataset, hashmap

Pardon my newbie-ness to Java as I am not experienced enough to know the most efficient way to do this. I have a hashmap like below, but it would have like 40,000 entries:

```
Map <String, String> someHashmap = new HashMap <String, String> ();
someHashmap.put("filepath1", null);
someHashmap.put("filepath2", "tag1");
someHashmap.put("filepath3", "tag2");
```

I want to determine how many value match `null` so that I can determine if any are null. Of course I could do a regular loop to check but am wondering if there is a more efficient way, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`containsValue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29) method, which states:

> Returns true if this map maps one or
>   more keys to the specified value.

```
somHashmap.containsValue(null);
```

However keep in mind, that if you have a large dataset(and it seems you do), you should create a separate data structure to keep track of the values that allow for O(1) lookup time, rather than O(n) time, as suggested in other answers.

Comment: But that would NOT be quick, in general. From the docs "will probably require time linear in the map size for most implementations of the Map interface." Not ver different than iterating over all the map

Comment: I think you can handle this stuff in code, it's just that you're going to build a few extra data structures similar to what the database would have. When you have enough different queries, the DB is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @leonboy: There are two meanings of *quick* - this is programmed quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative solution, designed for speed.

Call your original HashMap `a`. Have a second `HashMap<String, Integer> aCount`. The `aCount` hash map is going to store a count of how many of each value is in your original hash map.

Every time you insert a key `k` and value `v` into the first `HashMap`, check to see if `aCount.containsKey(v)`. If it does, then increment the value: `aCount.put(v, aCount.get(v) + 1)`. Otherwise, add a new entry: `aCount.put(v, 1)`.

Every time you remove a key `k` and value `v` from the first `HashMap`, check the count using `aCount.get(v)`. If the count is greater than one, then use `aCount.put(v, aCount.get(v) - 1)` to decrement the count. Otherwise (i.e. the count is exactly one) use `aCount.remove(v)`.

Then, you need only call `aCount.contains(v)` to find out whether or not a given value is in your HashMap `a`.

Why do all this? Because, this way, instead of having an O(n) query time to find out if a value exists in your HashMap, you get O(1) time. If this is valuable to you, then the above solution will work. If this doesn't matter to you, then you can easily use Mike Lewis's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need speed, you will neeed to store the used values in a HashSet, apart from the HashMap. For example (not tested!).

```
public class MapWithVals<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    protected final Set<V> vals = new HashSet<V>();

    public MapWithVals() {
        super();
    }

    public MapWithVals(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        super(m);
        vals.addAll(m.values());
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        super.clear();
        vals.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K arg0, V arg1) {
        vals.add(arg1);
        return super.put(arg0, arg1);
    }


    @Override
    public V remove(Object arg0) {
        V val = get(arg0);
        super.remove(arg0);
        if( ! super.containsValue(val) ) vals.remove(val);
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return vals.contains(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> arg0) {
        super.putAll(arg0);
        vals.addAll(arg0.values());
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work if there are duplicate values in the original hash map, and if you expect to ever remove an element from the original hash map.

Comment: Esp. since the OP is interested in nulls!

Comment: Your new code contains an error; you call your derived-class version of `containsValue()` instead of `super.containsValue()`. Even after adding that change, you've successfully made `containsValue()` O(1), but at the cost of making `remove()` O(n).

Comment: @jprete Thanks, fixed (had been already fixed before, but it slipped). And yes, in case of frequent `remove()` this gets inneficient - in that case one should implement a counter, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in `null`, everytime you `put` into the `HashMap`, you can check if the value is `null` and store the `key` in a `HashSet`.

Then you'd have to take care of sync'ing all CRUDs from the Map <--> HashSet